# Update Owin Token for Login and Role Selection

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am working on a WebAPI service for an application that I am working on, the application has some specific requirements:

- Every Request must be authorized
- Users are required to select a "Role" after logging in

In the application a Role can be explained as a business function which has multiple permissions associated with it.

I have implemented a WebAPI service using OWIN and have a working login which returns a token.  When the user selects their "Role" then I would like to update the token with the selected "Role" so all requests to the service will be able to identify what permissions the user has.

Does anyone know if there is a way to update the OWIN token and pass it back to the client for all future requests? i.e. add additional claims to the token

Comment: Could you please post some code

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [article](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/) for an explanation on how you can transform/ add claims on the fly. You may have to tweak the implementation to meet your needs. I am not able to provide any code since I don't have access to your implementation, but, the series from Taiseer is very informative. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.